# Ports and clients

Tags: javascript, android-studio, server, client-server, port

I'm creating a messaging application using client server sockets.

The device(DEVICE 1) creates the server and then clients join in on the specified port. Now if the same device(DEVICE 1) wants to create a second server, do I need to specify a different port to the one used for the first server. Or will this interfere with the 2 servers receiving data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Hint: Post effort and code

Comment: @mplungjan that's the thing. I haven't gotten round to coding multiple servers I'm kind of planning beforehand

Comment: Then it is perhaps an idea to try, see what happens and ask a more complete question? This is now likely to be voted down

Comment: @mplungjan ok thanks. I'll try it out.